# Query an ArcGIS Online FC via an HTTP request

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, request, http, hosted-feature-layer

I have data that is hosted by ArcGIS Online.

I want to query ArcGIS Online via an **HTTP request**. The response would be a JSON object (similar to [this](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/LocalGovernment/Events/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&f=pjson)).

---

What would it take to query a hosted ArcGIS Online FC via an HTTP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the previous answers, I have come across the following implementation:

## Step 1 - Register an application on ArcGIS online.

1. On you AGOL content page click **Add Item > An Application**.
2. On the **Add an application** window, select Application and give appropriate Title and Tags.
3. You will be redirected to the application overview page. Click **Setting** at the top right corner.
4. All the way at the bottom click **Registered Info**.
5. The information map as follows:
   a.  App ID = client_id
   b.  App Secret = client_secret

## Step 2 - Generate the token.

```
var client_id = "Your App Id";
var client_secret = "Your App Secret";
var grant_type = "client_credentials";
var feature_layer = 'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/LocalGovernment/Events/MapServer/0' // It will be your hosted feature layer
var urlTokenGenerator = `https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/oauth2/token?client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}&grant_type=${grant_type}&f=json`

// Generate a token
fetch(urlTokenGenerator).then(function (res) {
  return res.json();
}).then(function (data) {
  let _token = data["access_token"]
  console.log(`Your token is::${_token}`)
}
```

## Step 3 - Use the generated token on the subsequent request.

Code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<code id="code"></code>

  <script>
    var client_id = "Your App Id";
    var client_secret = "Your App Secret";
    var grant_type = "client_credentials";
    // It will be your hosted feature layer
    var feature_layer = 'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/LocalGovernment/Events/MapServer/0' 
    var urlTokenGenerator = `https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/oauth2/token?client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}&grant_type=${grant_type}&f=json`
    
    // Generate a token
    fetch(urlTokenGenerator).then(function (res) {
      return res.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
      let _token = data["access_token"]
      console.log(`Your token is::${_token}`)
      // Attaching the token to request url
      var fl_url = `${feature_layer}/query?returnGeometry=false&where=1%3D1&outFields=*&f=pjson&token=${_token}`
      fetch(fl_url).then(function (res) {
        return res.json()
      }).then(function (data) {
        let str = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        document.getElementById("code").innerText = str;
        console.log(data); // *data* is your response from the sever
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You will first need to make a request to AGOL to get an OAuth token, then append that token to your query request ("&token=<token)".

`https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/oauth2/token?client_id=<id>&client_secret=<secret>&grant_type=client_credentials`

You will need to registed an app in AGOL to get a clientID/Secret for your account, then plug those in above to get a token.

Comment: To add to @ericoneal's answer: Further information about tokens can be found here: > [Access ArcGIS token-secured web services](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.7/administer/windows/accessing-arcgis-token-secured-web-services.htm)
> > [About ArcGIS tokens](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.3/administer/linux/about-arcgis-tokens.htm)

Comment: [Generate an access token with OAuth 2.0 to access ArcGIS premium content and services.](https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/rest/get-an-access-token/)