# Query a JOINED ArcGIS Online resultset (via an HTTP request)

Tags: arcgis-online, attribute-joins, request, http, hosted-feature-layer

In a related question, we determined that it's possible to [query an ArcGIS Online FC via an HTTP request](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368283/query-an-arcgis-online-fc-via-an-http-request).

*(I'll refer to the feature class as FC1.)*

In addition to the above, I want to **dynamically join** from FC1 to a second feature class called FC2.

- The *join* could be described as: `Left join FC1 to FC2 on FC1.ID = FC2.ID`.

---

Can such a join be performed in ArcGIS Online -- in a way that allows the resultset to be served up to an external system? (as a JSON object that is requested via HTTP)

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to have to do this in two steps:

 1. query features from FC1 and collect the relevant keys that link to FC2
 2. query FC2 with an in clause specifying the keys collected in step 1.

Comment: I think the "Join Features" tool that you reference here is only on the Analyze tool in the AGOL webmap.  So you can effectively join them in the webmap (if you are the owner of both sets of data), but you wont be able to query it from a third party app as if it were a service.  That has been my experience, would love to be wrong about this....

Comment: I've never tried, but its definately worth  shot.  The results layer is a true feature service (you can see an item created in your content) so I assume you could query it with the endpoints as per any other feature service??

Comment: Be aware that using that 'join features' function currently breaks the setting that limits users visibility to their own records.  I assume it is because the output is not editable and that functionality is tied to editing.  Anything else related to editing could be suspect as well ...

Comment: It is possible with ArcGIS rest API.

Comment: @User1973 yeah, I did know it will be dynamic.  Just keep in mind you won't be able to edit that layer... You'll have to point any edits at the underlying feature service. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Join Features tool seems to have worked:

Steps:

1. [Add a feature layer to a web map](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/use-analysis-tools.htm) by using the [Join Features](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/join-features.htm) tool.

   - Note: I couldn't find the Content `-->` Analysis button in the new *Web Map Viewer (Beta)*.
   - I had to use the *classic Web Map Viewer instead.*
2. Create an application to authorize HTTP requests to AGOL

   - [Query an ArcGIS Online FC via an HTTP request](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368283/query-an-arcgis-online-fc-via-an-http-request)
   - Use the Feature Service URL from the new *join* feature layer.

---

And yes, the resulting feature layer is indeed **dynamic**.

I tested a few edits, and when I query the joined feature layer using the [aforementioned HTTP solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368283/query-an-arcgis-online-fc-via-an-http-request), the JSON response does, in fact, show  the updated data from the joined columns. So it worked as expected.

> From the [Join Features](http://From%20the%20Join%20Features%20tool%20(ArcGIS%20Online):) tool (ArcGIS Online):
>
> *"Create results as a **hosted feature layer** view allows the data to stay up
> to date as the source data changes."*
>
> https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/join-features.htm

Comment: yes, I don't have an idea about this. not even found in search.
https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/join-features.htm
ESRI has a search issue.
Good to see the solution.