# HTTPS post to ArcGIS Online feature layer

Tags: arcgis-online, integration, http, post, hosted-feature-layer

In an external system, I want to invoke an HTTPS post that would create records in ArcGIS Online.

Is there a mechanism in ArcGIS Online that can receive HTTPS posts?

Comment: HTTP isn't much used due to complete lack of security.  AGOL does things as *you* based on connection details that are embedded in the communication.

Comment: there is something https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/add-item.htm
here is the more specific answer.

Comment: @Vince : Would there be a reason why I couldn't use **tokens** for a POST request from an external system to AGOL, in the same way that I can use tokens for a [GET request from an external system to AGOL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368432/135445)?

Comment: In order to get that token, you need to send an HTTPS request, so there has to be *some* HTTPS. Once your code is configured to work correctly with HTTPS, stuffing all your requests in HTTPS POST messages is very nearly the path of least resistance.

Comment: Did you try using featureserver add-features? https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/add-features.htm

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS ESRI has Restful Service for ArcGIS Online.

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/add-item.htm

on the left side, you can read more articles to this with portal usage and ArcGIS online query.